# How to loop these if statements?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I am very new to programming and am having trouble understanding loops when not working with integers. I am trying to make an english to morse code translator and have this done so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class EnglishToMorse {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     System.out.println("Please enter text you wish to convert to Morse Code.");
     Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
     String english = sc.next();


         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
             System.out.print(".- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
             System.out.print("-... ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
             System.out.print("-.-. ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("D")){
             System.out.print("-.. ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("E")){
             System.out.print(". ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("F")){
             System.out.print("..-. ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("G")){
             System.out.print("--. ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){
             System.out.print(".... ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("I")){
             System.out.print(".. ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("J")){
             System.out.print(".--- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("K")){
             System.out.print("-.- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("L")){
             System.out.print(".-.. ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("M")){
             System.out.print("-- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
             System.out.print("-. ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("O")){
             System.out.print("--- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("P")){
             System.out.print(".--. ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")){
             System.out.print("--.- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("R")){
             System.out.print(".-. ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
             System.out.print("... ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("T")){
             System.out.print("- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("U")){
             System.out.print("..- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("V")){
             System.out.print("...- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("W")){
             System.out.print(".-- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("X")){
             System.out.print("-..- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
             System.out.print("-.-- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("Z")){
             System.out.print("--.. ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
             System.out.print(".---- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
             System.out.print("..--- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
             System.out.print("...-- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("4")){
             System.out.print("...- ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("5")){
             System.out.print("..... ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("6")){
             System.out.print("-.... ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("7")){
             System.out.print("--... ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("8")){
             System.out.print("---.. ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("9")){
             System.out.print("----. ");
         }
         if (english.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
             System.out.print("----- ");
         }


}
```

}

After numerous attempts trying out different lops and conditions, I cant get past the issue that my program can only translate one character. If I input more than one, it terminates. If someone could lead me on the right path in figuring out how to loop these if statements until all the characters are translated, I would be very grateful.

Comment: You are trying to compare the whole string. If the string is "hello", you should be translating each of the letters in it one by one - first the `h`, then the `e` and so on. To do this, you need to start at the zero-index letter, then go to the 1-index letter, and so on. Do you know the methods that give you the length of the string and the character at a given index?

Comment: Not sure, but if you could explain, that would be great!

Answer (score 3):

Use a `HashMap` to represent the translations:

```
HashMap<Character , String> char_to_morse = new HashMap<>();
char_to_morse.put('A' , ".- ");
//put all other chars in the map here

//retrieving a code:
System.out.print(char_to_morse.get(someChar));
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you successfully retrieve the user input word, you can then iterate over that word. Take a look at [toCharArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()). Per the documentation, it

> Converts this string to a new character array.

So your code would look like the following:

```
for (char c : english.toCharArray()){
    if (c == 'A'){
        System.out.print(".- ");
    }else if (c == 'B'){
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Note the following:

- You do not need to call `.equals` on `char c` because it is a primitive
- This implementation is using an enhanced for-loop. You can read more about them [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)

Comment: This answer + the one from Paul would be the best combination :)

Comment: How would I get the primitive c to ignore the case of the input?

Answer (score 0):

I would use this

```
char[] ca = english.toCharArray();
```

then you can loop

```
for (char c : ca) {
 //... your code        
}
```

and to improve some more use a switch syntax on the c

es.

```
switch (c) {
 case 'A':
    System.out.print(".- ");
    break;
default:
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String english;

while (sc.hasNext()){     //While there is another token in Scanner
   english = sc.next();   //Give the next token to english variable

   // Your code with the ifs

}
```